# In Spring, is it possible to return an image to the browser and include metadata about the image in the same response?

Tags: javascript, spring, metadata

I'm reading TIFF and PDF files off a network drive and returning each page as an image to the browser which get displayed as JPG.  This part works fine.  However I'm finding it inefficient because I first have to make a request to the server to determine how many pages the file has, which results in reading in the image on the server, getting the number of pages and returning that value.  Once that value is returned to the browser, I then have to make a request for each page to be returned as an image, so the file on the network drive is read in again, and the requested page number is returned as a byte[] representing a BufferedImage of the page.

What I'd ultimately like to do is make a request for the first page in the file, and then in the response to the browser, indicate the number of pages in the file so that each additional page can be requested.  This would reduce the amount of requests as no initial request would be required just to determine the number of pages.

I'm not sure if this is possible.  I've spent some time researching to see if I could get response headers from images, but haven't found anything.

Answer (score 0):

Why not adding the info to a cookie via reponse in your image-serving controller?

If you name the cookie in a way that would "link" it to a specific set of images you wouldn't need to hassle with "how can i read headers of an image?"

Comment: That sounds feasible, I'll give it a try :)